# get current position in list of inputs

Tags: jquery

I want to get the value of the input and the position after they 'blur' the input.

```
<span id="blah">
    <input type="text">a</input>        
    <input type="text">b</input>        
    <input type="text">c</input>        
    <input type="text">d</input> 
    ...
</span>

$('span input:text').live('blur', function(){

    var value = $(this).val();
}
```

so if they blur out of c i need it to return the value 'c' and the placement '3' in the list.

i cant change the HTML and the number of inputs may increase.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that the inputs are written `<input type="text">a</input>` rather than `<input type="text" value="a" />`? It's just that this will significantly change the answer.

Comment: Could you also specify which version of jQuery you're using? Version 1.7 changed things a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use index() method to get position. Can show you how to get it, however there is nothing in question to define "List"
http://api.jquery.com/index/

Your input html is invalid

```
   <input type="text" value="b" />


$('span input:text').live('blur', function(){
    var position=$(this).index()+1;/* index is zero based*/
    var value = $(this).val();
})
```

Comment: ug, beat me to it by a few seconds :-)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your blur function, you can do:

```
MyFunction($(this).val(), $(this).index());
```

Where MyFunction is the function you're calling that you want to pass the data to, the first parameter is the value of that textbox ('c" in your example), and the second is the index relative to it's siblings ("3" in your example, or rather "2", since it's 0-based).